# Java: metodo que almacene los parametros

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos, netbeans, servlets

Estoy haciendo un DAO y necesito insertar en dos tablas diferentes en la BDs. Se que lo puedo hacer con el `Autocommit`. Pero la idea es ir pasando las diferentes inserciones como parametro y usar el `Autocommit` en el metodo.
 El codigo lo simplifique le quite los try y catch.

El metodo que programe es este:

```
 public void reserva(String query) {

   Reserva rsv = new Reserva();
   dateString = sdfr.format(rsv.getFechaLlegada());
   PreparedStatement busquedaStmt = null;
   String busquedaString = query;

   busquedaStmt = 
   con.getConexion().prepareStatement(busquedaString);

   busquedaStmt.setString(1, dateString);
   ResultSet rs = busquedaStmt.executeQuery();

 }
```

Y lo utilizaria en el `servlet` de esta manera:

```
    ReservaDAOImp reserva = new ReservaDAOImp();
    reserva.reserva("INSERT INTO T_cliente (cliente) values (?)")
    reserva.reserva("INSERT INTO T_reserva (fechaLlegada) values
    (?)");
```

Comment: No entiendo del todo tu pregunta. Pero como veo la etiqueta `servlets`, deseo enfatizar bastante el punto de que te estás exponiendo a muchos problemas por estar usando una conexión global. Es algo que vemos a menudo en las preguntas aquí, pero es un patrón muy peligroso a evitar, en particular si estás trabajando en una aplicación web que probablemente tenga que manejar varios usuarios a la vez.

Comment: OK..gracias..que patron deberia usar.. y con respecto a la pregunta... necesito crear un metodo que utilice el `Autocommit`... y pero el problema que se me presenta es que no se como manejar los argumentos en el metodo... Creo que deberia hacer una `arraylist` que almacene las instrucciones de la BDs y crear otro metodo que haga correr las consultas...no se si me explique bien...

Comment: No sé a qué te refieres cuando hablas del `Autocommit`.

Comment: Buscalo en Google..

Comment: Yo sé lo que es, pero la forma como usas el término no tiene sentido. Por eso pregunto.

Comment: El `Autocommit` lo uso para mandar mas de una consulta a la BDs, en este caso dos, pero al estar dentro de un metodo (y como los metodos tienen argumentos) necesito pasar como argumento las consultas (`String query`) . Lo tengo pensado hacer es crear un `LinkedList` para ir almacenando las consultas. Y luego, hago un `setAutocommit(false)`. Una vez que tengo las consultas con el `PreparedStatement` lleno lo placeholders ( es decir, los `?`) con los respectivos valores y hago un `commit()`.

Comment: Eso tiene mas sentido, porque en la pregunta suena a todo lo contrario. Suena a que usas el auto-commit para ejecutar varias sentencias. Pero en realidad es lo contrario. En vez de usar el auto commit, usas una transacción y controlas el momento de hacer el commit. Es importante ser claro.

Comment: En cuanto a tu pregunta, suena a que estás tratando de diseñar un método genérico que puede aceptar cualquier tipo de SQL. En general, cuando se trata de la capa de datos, es mejor hacer lo contrario, o sea crear métodos específicos a cada operación que necesitas.

Comment: Disculpa. A que te referis con  `transaccion` . Tengo entendido que el `autocommit` es para eso poner las consultas en cola de espera y una vez listo para enviar a la BD usas el `commit`.

Comment: No. *autocommit* es todo lo contrario. *autocommit* significa, como su propio nombre indica, de que el commit se ejecuta de forma automática después de cada sentencia. Por eso tu dices que usas el `setAutoCommit(false)`, o sea que desactivas el *autocommit* para que el *commit* no se ejecute de forma automática después de cada sentencia. Cuando ejecutas varias sentencias y le haces *commit* a todas ellas de un solo, esto se llama una transacción. O sea que, aunque ejecutas varias sentencias, desde el punto de vista de la base de datos, es como si todas se hubieran ejecutado de forma atómica.

Comment: claro...si...gracias... Entonces  yo tengo un clase con getters y setters ` Reserva` y `ReservaImplentacion` . Los metodos para insertar ¿ Los creo en cada implementacion que tienen las clases.. ? ..

Comment: Por lo que veo aca hay un error de concepto grande. No deberias mandar el insert escrito a ningun proceso. Mas alla de los problemas que marca sstan, Tu clase deberia tener un metodo reserva.agregarclienteareserva, reserva.agregarfechaareserva, las cuales solo recibirian los parametros necesarios para ese query, que ya se sabe cual es. Lo que estas haciendo es pasar los querys a una capa donde no parece que debieran estar. y estas embarrando procesos solo por el hecho de "ahorrar" codigo, y no estas ahorrando nada.

Comment: `Lo que estas haciendo es pasar los querys a una capa donde no parece que debieran estar` ... a que capa te referis... y com deberia hacer ... ya que conceptualmente no entiendo mucho.